# Does this square of $\delta$-functors anti-commute?

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$ be abelian categories, and let $F^\bullet: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be a cohomological $\delta$-functor.

Recall that a cohomological $\delta$-functor is a series of additive functors $F^{n}: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ for $n \geq 0$ along with morphisms $\delta_{ABC}^n: F^n{C} \rightarrow F^{n+1}{A}$ for any short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathcal{A}$. A cohomological $\delta$-functor must satisfy these two properties

1. For any short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ in $\mathcal{A}$, there is a long exact sequence

$$
0 \rightarrow F^0(A) \rightarrow F^0(B) \rightarrow F^0(C) \xrightarrow{\delta_{ABC}^0}  F^1(A) \rightarrow F^1(B)...
$$

2. If we have a morphism of long exact sequences

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> C @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> A' @>>> B' @>>> C' @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$

then the following diagram commutes.

$$
\require{AMDcd}
\begin{CD}
F^n(C) @>{\delta^n_{ABC}}>> F^{n+1}(A) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
F^n(C') @>{\delta^n_{A'B'C'}}>> F^{n+1}(A') \\
\end{CD}
$$

Suppose that we have a commuting square of short exact sequences:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 @. \\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> C @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> D @>>> E @>>> F @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> H @>>> I @>>> J @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
@. 0 @. 0 @. 0 @.
\end{CD}
$$

Then, does this square anti-commute?

$$
\require{AMDcd}
\begin{CD}
F^n(J) @>{\delta^n_{HIJ}}>> F^{n+1}(H) \\
@VV{\delta^n_{CFJ}}V @VV{\delta^{n+1}_{ADH}}V \\
F^{n+1}(C) @>{\delta^{n+1}_{ABC}}>> F^{n+2}(A) \\
\end{CD}
$$

Cohomological $\delta$-functors are meant to generalize other "cohomology" functors found in homological algebra, such as the cohomology of a cochain complex and right-derived functors. In both of these examples, the square above does anticommute. But I have not been able to solve prove it for general cohomological $\delta$-functors.

Comment: A lot depends on your conventions and notations for the snake lemma, but I think that the last square *anti*-commutes.

Comment: You're corrrect, thank you! I updated the question to ask about anti-commutativity instead.

Comment: Pretty sure this is proposition III.4.1 in Cartan-Eilenberg, more or less. In their book, additive functors are defined between categories of modules, but I'm reasonably confident that you can turn the element-wise parts of the proof into general nonsense, if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you, that book contains the answer!